# Optimize gremlin queries in Cosmos DB

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb

I run the queries likes the following in gremlin in Cosmos Graph:

```
g.V().hasLabel('vertex_label').limit(1)
```

This query is problematic in concern of size of data which returned from DB as this query returns all `inE` and `outE` of the selected vertex. The question is *how can I optimize this query in notion of size of query result?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, the mentioned query returns a vertex with all its dependencies and connections.  Therefore, it can be problematic in high volume of data (when there are a lot of connection with the specified vertex). Hence, We can optimize our queries using something likes `properties`, `properyMap`, `values`,and `valueMap`. In sum, `valueMap(true)` in the end of related queries can be useful and minimize the size of the transferred data from Cosmos. For example:

```
g.V().hasLabel('play').limit(1).valueMap(true)
```

The boolean value is for getting `id` and `label` of the vertex in addition to vertex properties.

Also, If there is any notion of optimization in the structure of a query, you can find more in [this link](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Traversal-Optimization).

Answer (score 0):

How are you using CosmosDB Graph, via Microsoft.Azure.Graphs SDK or Gremlin server?

If you are using Microsoft.Azure.Graphs, the latest version ([0.2.4-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Graphs/0.2.4-preview) as of posting) supports specifying the `GraphSONFormat` as a parameter on `DocumentClient.CreateGremlinRequest(..)`. You can choose from either `GraphSONFormat.Normal` or `GraphSONFormat.Compact` and `Compact` should be the default if it is not supplied.

For the CosmosDB Gremlin server, `Compact` is also the default behavior.

With `GraphSONFormat.Compact`, vertex results won't include edges and as a result, `outE` and `inE` fetches can be skipped when fetching the vertex. `GraphSONFormat.Normal` will return the full GraphSON response if this is desired.

**Additional Note**: There are optimizations on `limit()` that will be included in the next release of SDK/server, so I would expect additional perf gains on the traversal example that you provided when the release becomes available.